# Trouble about iterating over an array to generate frequencies in a hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array with some different data (in string format) and I would like to count the frequencies of each value and store it in hash/dictonary, but i'm getting error trying to do it.

I would like to do something like this:

```
    words = ["foo", "var", "spam", "egg", "foo", "foo", "egg"]
    frequency = {}
    words.each{|word| frequency[word] += 1}
```

and get the following output:

```
   puts(frequency)   #{"foo" => 3, "var" => 1, "spam" => 1, "egg" => 2}
```

but I'm getting the following problem:

```
    prueba.rb:3:in `block in <main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is there another way of accomplishing the same result?

Answer (score 4):

If you query the hash for a key not present you get `nil`, that's the problem. Let's make `0` the default if a key is not present

```
frequency = Hash.new(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
words.each{|word| frequency[word] += 1}
```

It's equivalent to:

```
words.each{|word| frequency[word] = frequency[word] + 1}
```

However, `frequency` hash is empty and `frequency[word]` returns `nil` -- essentially, you are trying to do `nil + 1`, which results in the error you are getting.

You can initialize new elements of the hash manually:

```
words.each{|word| frequency[word] ||= 0; frequency[word] += 1}
```

Or, as other answers have already suggested, use `frequency = Hash.new(0)` as a shortcut.

Comment: That's a good explanation. I wanted to add even `frequency.fetch(word, 0)` before introducing the default for the hash

Comment: @Ursus thanks. :-) Oh yes, `fetch` is also an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = ["foo", "var", "spam", "egg", "foo", "foo", "egg"]

words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |w, h| h[w] += 1 }
#=> {"foo"=>3, "var"=>1, "spam"=>1, "egg"=>2}
```

[#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is the enumerator which iterates by passing each element with an object supplied (here `Hash.new(0)`) and returns that supplied object in next iteration.

`Hash.new(0)` creates a hash where default value of any key is  0.

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
hash['a'] #=> 0
```

We use this property of default value and simply pass each word to the object and increment the counter.
 :)

Issue in your code: You don't have default value in your case, so you would need to do that manually by checking if a key exists in the hash or not.

Comment: JesusJPG, if you are confused by `each_with_object` (which is used a lot in Ruby), it's almost the same as `h = Hash.new(0); words.each { |w| h[w] += 1 }; h`. Mainly, it saves two lines of code: the initialisation of the hash and the hash after it has been modified. (It also confines `h` to the block, away from prying eyes.) If `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value. `h[k] += 1` expands to `h[k] = h[k] + 1`, which, if `h` has no key `k`, becomes `h[k] = 0 + 1`, `0` being the default. Note `[]` is the method `Hash#[]=` on the left of `=`, `Hash#[]` on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. By initializing it with Hash.new(0)

```
names = ["foo", "var", "spam", "egg", "foo", "foo", "egg"]

names.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |total, e| total[e] += 1 ;total}

# {"foo"=>3, "var"=>1, "spam"=>1, "egg"=>2}
```